# I can't update an existing record and I want an action not to behave as edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are two questions.

First, I want to enable an action to update successfully.
Now I don't know why I can't update successfully.

Second,
I want to edit and update a column of existing record, and I found that if I make an action get and correspond to an action which acts as a put action, the get action is recognized as an existence of edit,
I don't hope this, so how can I fix it?

view `split_now.html.erb`

```
<div class="container">
 <h1>Split</h1>
 <%= form_for @currency, url: { action: 'split', controller: 'currencies'}, method: :put do |f|%>
  <% if @currency.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger">
        <h2><%= @currency.errors.count %>error(s) exist(s).</h2>
        <ul>
          <% @currency.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>amount whatever you want to issue like 100</p>
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= f.number_field :amount,:class=>'form-control form-group',placeholder:"amount",min:"1",step:"1",required:true%>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'done', class: "btn btn-large bg-info" %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

currencies_contoroller.rb

```
def split_now
  @currency=Currency.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end


def split
   @currency=Currency.find_by_slug(params[:id])
  if CurrencyUser.where(currency_id:@currency.id,owner:true).first.user==current_user
    issue_more(params,@currency)
  else
    redirect_to @currency,alert:"This currency wasn't issued by you"
  end
end

def issue_more(params,currency)
   result=false
   current_amount=currency.amount
  result=currency.increment("amount",params[:amount].to_i)
 currency_user=CurrencyUser.find_by(currency_id:currency.id,owner:true)
 currency_user.increment("amount",params[:amount].to_i)
 return result
end`
```

routes

```
 resources :currencies do
  member do
    put :split
    get :split_now
  end
 end
```

---

```
       Started PUT "/currencies/hello/split" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 23:50:42 +0900
     Processing by CurrenciesController#split as HTML
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zZHYVV3AqI6fiqtY47XJTP1iOte1gRzwSPw4NEHHtfWnf0QHNrRnS1fzD+KCIrAm93eKROb1YynGmcwlhx6Vtw==", "currency"=>{"amount"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"done", " 
 id"=>"hello"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   Currency Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "currencies".* FROM "currencies" WHERE "currencies"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "hello"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 CurrencyUser Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "currency_users".* FROM "currency_users" WHERE "currency_users"."currency_id" = $1 AND "currency_users"."owner" = $2 ORDER BY "currency_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  
[["currency_id", 2], ["owner", "t"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CurrencyUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "currency_users".* FROM "currency_users" WHERE "currency_users"."currency_id" = $1 AND "currency_users"."owner" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["currency_id", 2], ["owner", "t"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering currencies/split.html.erb within layouts/application
 Rendered currencies/split.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
 Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.4ms)
 Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 181ms (Views: 145.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
```

Comment: Can you paste the Error and message from console log?

Comment: I don't know why there was no error. but I updated the question to show you the console log.

Comment: As per your console log, every query is for select, so there is not update query you have written in your code.
But in last method you are increasing the amount by calling `increment` method, first of all try to check if that method is being called or not.

Comment: One more thing I didn't understand that `  result=currency..increment("amount",params[:amount].to_i)` is this double dot .. are intentional?

Comment: Oh I don't know why the code included double dots but actually, the code here doesn't contain double dots.

Comment: yes the part of code is called as I see this #<Currency id: 2, name: "Hello", description: "", price: #<BigDecimal:7f963729ab10,'0.1E1',9(18)>, amount: 97, name_short: "HHL", image: nil, created_at: "2018-03-21 10:16:39", updated_at: "2018-03-28 16:24:32", slug: "hello"> but it isnt updated I dont know why even though I entered 3 and it must have been 100

Comment: Can you please paste code of `increment` method here.

Comment: p result=currency.increment("amount",params[:amount].to_i)
 currency_user=CurrencyUser.find_by(currency_id:currency.id,owner:true)
p currency_user.increment("amount",params[:amount].to_i)